# Dynamic expression to encode and decode in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dynamic-expression

I am looking equivalent function encoding decoding my content for content-Md5 property of my blob. I tried Base64ToString and I get this

O؈�T�eK̲; x���*

See the sample code in c# below. I am looking to achieve same functionality for my input in logic app:

```
 var hashStr = "INDiTF0Nq8hU6d4fHqu1dQ==";
 var hash = Convert.FromBase64String( hashStr );
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
    
 foreach( var b in hash )
 {
     sb.Append( b.ToString("X2") );
 }
 sb.ToString().Dump();
```

I get output as **20D0E24C5D0DABC854E9DE1F1EABB575**

How to built dynamic expression to get same output in logic app when I have my string value **"INDiTF0Nq8hU6d4fHqu1dQ=="**

Note: remember the format is "X2"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some test, it seems difficult for us to implement the requirement in logic app by actions or expressions directly. So I suggest you to use azure function in your logic app.

You can [create a new azure function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function#create-a-function-app) and [create an HTTP trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function#create-function) in the function app.

Then you can write the same code in the HTTP trigger function, below is my function code:

[image]

Then go to your logic app and [create function action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) in it, it will request the function which you created above to do the convert. My logic app show as below:

[image]

After running the logic app, the result show as:

[image]